# Weird inconsistent reads from large files with Samsung NVME drives

Tags: nvme

I have a new machine with 2 Samsung M.2 drives (one is the Samsung SSD 960 PRO 1TB, and one the 512GB variant). Mainboard is the ASRock X99 Taichi. Installation of Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-37 went without problems. During operation I noticed some weird errors while reading large files that looked like the files were corrupt. After repeatedly copying the files from remote I noticed that SHA1 and MD5 checksums were completely inconsistent.

In fact, I can reproduce the behavior, on both drives, by producing a large enough file with random contents via

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock of=output.dat  bs=1G  count=4
4+0 Datensätze ein
4+0 Datensätze aus
4294967296 Bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) kopiert, 21.2289 s, 202 MB/s
```

Running MD5 or SHA1 on the files gives inconsistent hashes:

```
$ sha1sum output.dat 
c6a00127512741fa54555bee23eb05bbf5b09be1  output.dat
$ sha1sum output.dat
70c256358f8bc77a8c43c4cc0f03611cce4c6599  output.dat
$ md5sum output.dat 
37f5694f9fa6e9869a3214053b539207  output.dat
$ md5sum output.dat
134d060edb5c392597cd8c8ddf5e1b5a  output.dat
```

The weird thing is, if I do this with smaller files (e.g. `dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock of=output.dat  bs=1G  count=1`) I don't see the behavior (hashes are consistent). I wasn't able to find any specific file size that triggers the behavior, yet.

I already updated the BIOS and memchecked the RAM - everything seemed to be ok. I'm not sure how to further diagnose this problem.

There is no output appearing in `dmesg`. Again, I'm reproducing the behavior with randomly generated files here, but I see the same behavior in real files if they are large enough. Discs are formatted as ext4 and ext3. Both discs show the behavior.

Comment: I know it's an old bug, but do you have `discard` in your mount options? If yes, mount them without `discard` and try again.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help :( The problem still remains the same.

Comment: We noticed that the problem was not happening when we only left 1 RAM module and one of the SSDs on the board. After we inserted all 4 RAM modules again, the problem was gone. Only if we operate with 2 NVME SSDs now we again see the problem. Very strange. We thought it might be a broken RAM but now the system is running smoothly under heavy load with all RAM modules and one of the SSDs. This seems either a problem with the mainboard, or with one of the SSDs, or with a subtle linux driver bug that happens only with 2 different SSDs (again, the problem did not happen under Win10...).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem seems to be related to the ASRock X99 Taichi board that does not seem to correctly handle quad channel mode. Disabling quad channel mode in BIOS (or plugging in the RAM in the first 4 slots) resolved the problem. I cannot recommend this mainboard to anyone. It caused us some really weird, really hard to debug problems.